# Delay relay using millis

Tags: arduino

I need help adding a delay. When the `green` output pin is `LOW`, I need to delay for 1 minute, and then make the `relay` output `LOW`. This delay should not stop execution of the code, because if `state` becomes `HIGH` again, the timer should be ignored.

```cpp
int Green = 18;
int Relay = 12;
int Input = 4;
int state = LOW;
int val = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(RED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Green, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Relay, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Input, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  val = digitalRead(Input);
  if (val == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(RED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Green, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Relay, HIGH);
    delay(100);

    if (state == LOW) {
      Serial.println("Motion detected!");
      state = HIGH;
    }
  }
  else {
      digitalWrite(RED, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Green, LOW);
      delay(700);
      **digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);**  **<...... need the Delay here**
      delay(20);

      if (state == HIGH){
        Serial.println("Motion stopped!");
        state = LOW;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without stopping the code"?  You can delay a minute by doing `delay(60000);`, but the code is not going to continue.  What you have here does not have a loop.  Is there other code calling this?  If so, then you have to start checking the elapsed time.

Comment: You should tag your post with arduino I believe... All you ask has nothing to do with C++ in general and milliseconds is really not a valid tag. If you want to have events in none sequential order, you have to build a state machine, trigger it by other events and timers. There is, as I know, nothing in C++ nor arduino, which lets you execute something at a specific time depending on given context. You need at minimum a timer and a callback.

Comment: I am not sure what is unclear about this question.  Voting to re-open.  The solution in outline:  For each periodic "task", in `loop()` declare a `static unsigned long` variable initialised to `millis()`.  e.g. `static unsigned long period_100 = millis() ;`.  Then on each iteration get `unsigned long now = millis() ;`.  Then the part that is to be executed periodically (100ms in this case) is wrapped in `if( now - period_100 >= 100 ){ period_100 = now ; /* 100ms code here... */ }`.  You can do that for multiple periodic tasks using a separate static variable.

Comment: Updated the tags to get the audience you need - those that will understand what you are asking.  It is a common issue in Arduino because 1) the `delay()` function exists, but it is an _executive loop_ framework that should not use it. 2) Pretty much all of the examples in the official documentation are poorly written in this respect and not conducive to real-time.  Your `loop()` should be written as a non-blocking state-machine.

Comment: ... regarding my "solution" it is generalised for periodic tasks.  For single shot timers there is some additional code needed, not conducive to comments.  Needs to get re-opened.  Alternatively delete this question, take note of the comments and start again (with appropriate tags), and don't double-space your code.  It is easier to understand if we can see more of it without scrolling.

Comment: Here, example one-shot polled timer class using `millis()`: https://create.arduino.cc/editor/cpns/0c1dfcf4-416a-4be3-9bae-1c8b4c53c3db/preview

Comment: The question is unclear (to me) but I voted to reopen because you understand it and have an answer. I don't understand the answer either, but would be happy to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track but you did needed few more variables and also using temporary tracking of time using millis() in order to achieve non-blocking code

Here is a simple example that should do what you are asking or at least close enough. I renamed some of your variables just to make more sense to someone else reading the code as things like RED or Green don't really explain much!

```
int led_pin = 18;
int relay_pin = 12;
int sensor_pin = 4;

bool detected = false;
bool stop_relay = false;
unsigned long motion_stopped_time = 0; //will track the elapsed time after the motion stop

void setup() {
  pinMode(led_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sensor_pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop(){

  if(digitalRead(sensor_pin) == HIGH){ //the sensor has detected motion

        //enclose the code here so it only executes once when motion is detected
        if(detected == false){
            Serial.println("Motion detected!");
            detected = true;

            digitalWrite(led_pin, HIGH); //turn led on
            digitalWrite(relay_pin, HIGH); //switch the relay on

        }

  }else{ //the sensor has stopped detecting motion

      if(detected == true){ //execute this only once when motion stops
            Serial.println("Motion stopped!");
            detected = false;

            digitalWrite(led_pin, LOW); //turn the led off

            motion_stopped_time = millis(); //remember the current time
            stop_relay = true;

       }else{
          if(stop_relay == true){ // ensures that this block will only execute once after the delay timer logic below

            //the current millis() time is 60sec more than the remembered time when the motion stopped
            if(millis() - motion_stopped_time >= 60000){
                digitalWrite(relay_pin, LOW); //switch the relay off
                stop_relay = false; 
            }

          }
       }
  }
}
```